# angular date picker issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using `ngbdatepicker` for my form. I am trying to save date as a separately. I need to get date as bellow.

```
<input class="form-control ngbfield custom-form-control" required [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':f.touched && birthDay.invalid}" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dob" [readonly]="true" #birthDay="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="signupModel.birthDay" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker"/>
```

date is passed successfully. I console logged below values.

```
console.log(this.signupModel.birthDay.year);
console.log(this.signupModel.birthDay.day);
console.log(this.signupModel.birthDay.month);
```

above values printed correctly. but my problem is in error occurred in the terminal. Please check my screen shot.
[image]

How I rectify this?

Comment: Can you please share details about the type of class property `signupModel.birthDay`? I think the problem is caused by assigning wrong type to the property `signupModel.birthDay`.

Comment: can you please provide working demo ?

Comment: birthday: Date;

Comment: Hi Jins , 
birthday: Date;

Answer (score 0):

seems like your `birthDay`-variable is defined with the type "Date".
the original JS "Date" object did not have those properties!

ngbdatepicker uses a simple model: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples

```js
Model: {
  "year": 2020,
  "month": 1,
  "day": 16
}
```

please show your type-definition of `birthDay`.

you should define it like this:

```js
signupModel: {
  /* your properties here */
  birthDay: { year: number, month: number, day: number }
  /* more properties here */
};
```

live-demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-4?file=app%2Fdatepicker-basic.ts

Comment: Hi mxii, i need to re-assign that year, month, day values separately as below
this.signupModel.birthYear = year; this.signupModel.birthMonth = month;
 this.signupModel.birthDate = day;

Comment: show the complete signup-form component.. .ts and .html.. maybe using stackblitz.com

Comment: i need to save year, day, month separately (different column in Database) therefore i need to re-assign that values as a separate models

Comment: see my last edit, live-demo.. should work like expected! :)